# Prevent multiple jQuery animations from happening at the same time

Tags: jquery, resize, jquery-animate

This question may seem similar to other questions about preventing animations queuing, but this question is different.

I created a simplified example on jsFiddle for illustration purposes. (In this example, #box could just be set to width:50%, but the real application I am working on is more complicated and requires complex calculations on the box elements).

I have a container with a box inside. When the container is resized, the box should be animated and resized to a certain size.

However, if you resize the result box slowly (over a period of 1 second), the #box resizes in a jerky way.

http://jsfiddle.net/B7UGm/

```
$('#container').resize(function() {
    $("#box").animate({'width':$('#container').width() * 0.5});
});
```

Optimally, I would like to merge the animations into one so that it changes size in a nice smooth way.

Thanks!

Comment: As with the other questions you might have found, applying `.stop(true, true)` seems to make it less jerky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `stop(true, true)`.

```
$('#container').resize(function() {
    $("#box").stop(true, true).animate({'width':$('#container').width() * 0.5});
});
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B7UGm/2/)***

Answer (score 4):

you may use css3 transitions, for example:

```
#box
{
transition: width 2s;
-moz-transition: width 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: width 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: width 2s; /* Opera */
}
```

let me know if this works :)

Comment: If this is a possible option, it might be the best way to do it. It makes the animation so much smoother, and needs no fancy javascript logic. http://jsfiddle.net/B7UGm/4/

Comment: iv used it several times in the past :)
and it works with most of the properties like background color, so u can make fading backgrounds.. or smoothly animated headers....

Comment: Yes, this is a great solution, but unfortunately, IE8 and IE9 doesn't support it css3 transitions :(

Comment: @joshli so dont support them :p hhhh

Answer (score 0):

u can also use .delay()
for example:

```
$('#foo').slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
```